# How to rewrite this script to shorten it?

Tags: jquery

https://codepen.io/DimaDolgoter/pen/NBaERM?editors=0110

```js
$(".btn-hide").hide(); //скрываем кнопку скрытия
$(".btn-show").hide(); //скрываем кнопку показа
if ($('.block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) label').length > 9) { //если элементов больше 9
  $('.block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) label:nth-child(n+9)').hide(); //скрываем их
  $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-show").show(); //показываем кнопку для показа всех скрытых элементов
  $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-show").click(function() { //при клике на кнопку показа
    $(".block-filter__inputs label").first().show(100, function showNext() {
      $(this).next("label").show(100, showNext);
    }); //постепенно показываем елементы
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-show").hide(); //скрываем кнопку показа
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-hide").show(); //показываем кнопку скрытия 
  });

  $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-hide").click(function() { //при клике на кнопку скрытия
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) label").last().hide(100, function hideNext() {
      $(this).prev("label:nth-child(n+9)").hide(100, hideNext); //скрывыаем элементы кроме первых восьми
    });
    $(this).hide(); //скрываем кнопку скрытия
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(1) .btn-show").show(); ///показываем кнопку показа
  });
}





if ($('.block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) label').length > 9) {
  $(" .block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-show").show();
  $('.block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) label:nth-child(n+9)').hide(); //если элементов больше 9 то 

  $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-show").click(function() {
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) label").first().show("fast", function showNext() {
      $(this).next("label").show("fast", showNext);
    });
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-show").hide();
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-hide").show();
  });

  $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-hide").click(function() {
    $(".block-filter__inputs label").last().hide("fast", function hideNext() {
      $(this).prev("label:nth-child(n+9)").hide("fast", hideNext);
    });
    $(this).hide();
    $(".block-filter__inputs:nth-child(2) .btn-show").show();
  });
}
```

1) How to shorten it? Because I think that duplicating the function for every time `nth-child` selector is not cool.

2) When I use `.hide()` or `.show()` elements are "jumping". Click on "show" or "hide" to see that.

Comment: yes. i were edit question

Comment: With regards to #1, you can store the result of `$(selector)` in a variable.  And you can also select a common parent to most of your things and perform additional `find(childSelector)` off that variable when you need to find children.

Comment: it this still an issue? did anyone provide the answer you were looking for?

Comment: ^^bumping^^ this thread again

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your function... I changed it quite a lot.

1. The show/hide button now have a common class to toggle them.
2. The show/hide buttons now have their own handler that works for any `.block-filter__inputs` div... So you can now have as much of these as you which without duplicating code **(I think that was the main question)**.
3. There is some variables to set the animation params, such as the delay and the amount of elements to show.
4. The [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method is used to target the elements.
5. The `index` provided by `.each()` is used to set a [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) before the animation of each elements.
6. `.get()` is used on `elementToHide` to make it an array and be able to reverse it. The result is wrapped with `$()` to make it a jQuery collection again.

```js
// Hide the show/hide buttons on load.
$(".btn-show,.btn-hide").hide();

// Animation params.
var maxElToShow = 8;
var animationDelay = 100;

// For each block, hide the extra elements based on maxElToShow.
$('.block-filter__inputs').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('label').length >= maxElToShow){ // if there are more than 9 elements
    $(this).find('label:nth-child(n+'+maxElToShow+')').hide(); // hide them
    $(this).find(".btn-show").show();  // show the button to show all hidden items
  }
});

// A handler for all btn-show.
$( ".btn-show" ).click( function() {
  
  // Get the collection of elements to show.
  var elementToShow = $(this).parent(".block-filter__inputs").find("label").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).index()>=maxElToShow) ? $(this) : false;
  });
  
  // Gradually show them.
  elementToShow.each(function(index,element){
    $(element).delay(index*animationDelay).fadeIn(animationDelay);
  });

  // Toggle the show/hide buttons.
  $(this).closest(".block-filter__inputs").find(".showHide").toggle();
}); // End click.


// A handler for all btn-hide.
$(".btn-hide").click(function() {
  
  // Get the collection of elements to hide.
  var elementToHide = $(this).parent(".block-filter__inputs").find("label").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).index()>=maxElToShow) ? $(this) : false;
  });

  // Reverse the collection of elements to animate backward.
  var elementToHideReversed = $(elementToHide.get().reverse());

  // Gradually hide them.
  elementToHideReversed.each(function(index,element){
    $(element).delay(index*animationDelay).fadeOut(animationDelay);
  });

  // Toggle the show/hide buttons.
  $(this).closest(".block-filter__inputs").find(".showHide").toggle();
}); // END click
```

```css
label{
  position: relative;
  margin:5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block-filter__inputs">

  <label for="">1</label>
  <label for="">2</label>
  <label for="">3</label>
  <label for="">4</label>
  <label for="">5</label>
  <label for="">6</label>
  <label for="">7</label>
  <label for="">8</label>
  <label for="">9</label>
  <label for="">10</label>
  <label for="">11</label>

  <div class="btn-show showHide">show</div>
  <div class="btn-hide showHide">hide</div>
</div>

<div class="block-filter__inputs">

  <label for="">1</label>
  <label for="">2</label>
  <label for="">3</label>
  <label for="">4</label>
  <label for="">5</label>
  <label for="">6</label>
  <label for="">7</label>
  <label for="">8</label>
  <label for="">9</label>
  <label for="">10</label>
  <label for="">11</label>
  <label for="">12</label>
  <label for="">13</label>
  <label for="">14</label>

  <div class="btn-show showHide">show</div>
  <div class="btn-hide showHide">hide</div>
</div>
```

I did not investigate the "jumpy" effect on hide in your script... Since I completely changed the way to do it.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BPwXKv?editors=0010) to play with...